# Where does `signup`, `login`, `register` methods come from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In this piece of code:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :line_items
  map.resources :orders
  map.resources :products
  map.resources :categories

  map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
  map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
  map.register '/register', :controller => 'user', :action => 'create'
  map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'user', :action => 'new'
  map.connect '/add-to-cart', :controller => 'line_items', :action => 'new'
end
```

`map` object has methods `connect` and `resources` called, which are described in [ActionController documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing/RouteSet/Mapper.html). Where are the other ones defined/described? They were generated by RESTful authentication plugin.

How should I map `/add-to-cart` to its action/controller, to have automatically `add_to_cart_path` method generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [named routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's done via the magic of `method_missing`.